# The Center of a Simple Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I’m trying to understand this statement regarding simple groups from *Naive Lie Theory* by John Stillwell.

> The center of any group G is a normal subgroup of G, hence G cannot be simple unless Z(G)={1}.

---

My question is, what if $Z(G) = G$ (i.e. G is Abelian)? Then the statement is of no value because it simply says $G$ is a normal subgroup of itself, a trivial statement.

**If G is a nontrivial Abelian group, can it not be simple?** This statement appears to claim that $Z(G) \neq \{1\} \implies G$ is not simple.

It seems to me the textbook is overlooking this important case, when $G$ is nontrivial and Abelian.

Comment: Yes, simple abelian groups exist, and they are precisely the finite cyclic groups of prime order.

Comment: @BW. Great, this is what I expected. Then how can we reconcile Stillwell’s statement?

Comment: You can reconcile Stillwell's statement by adding the hypothesis that $G$ is not abelian. (Maybe this assumption is already elsewhere in the text, I have not read it.) But it is also good to know about the abelian case, which you noticed, to your credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and the book is wrong (or you missed a condition). Any cyclic group of prime order is simple and has non-trivial center.